# Is my proof of a limit using epsilon delta correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I'm doing calculus by myself without a tutor. The proving of limits using the formal definition of a limit was quite strange to me.

I tried to do an exercise and I think I might have done it correctly but I can't know if I've done it right without someone looking at it.

It would be a huge help to me if someone could tell me if I've done it right or where I might have gone wrong.

Here is the proof:

[image: proof]

Comment: I think the writing could use some work, but your logic seems totally correct. (just fyi though: in the future it would be preferred if you could write everything out in MathJax instead of linking an image)

Comment: Thank you very much.